# shell split file into multiple files and delete in old file

Tags: shell

I have text file where it contains data like below,

test.txt

```
abcd
1234
abcd1
1234a
```

shell script/command to split the file into multiple files if the having the matching pattern like

x.txt should contain below content

```
abcd
abcd1
```

y.txt should contain below content

```
1234
1234a
```

Comment: What is the criteria for determining what lines are grouped together? How much of a prefix?

Comment: we need to group all the similar words into new file irrespective of how many times it repeated.  For example if had a file like abcd abcdef abcdefg 123 123a 123abc here I want to get abcd containing lines to one file and 123 to another

Comment: What about abxyz?

Comment: What is the minimum length for the prefix? 1, 2, 3 characters?  If there are a set of lines starting `abc` with different letters (not `d`) next, should all the `abc` lines be in one file, or should the `abcd` lines be in one file (and `abca` in another, and `abcb`, and `abc1`, and `abc2` etc be in other files)?  What are the rules for determining when lines belong in one file vs in several files.

Comment: I don't have any specific prefix. all the abc letters containing words should be in the same file regardless of their prefix and suffix.Basically I have file with data as above mentioned I want iterate through file and get all similar one to different file I don't have any condition to check that

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` with `-l` flag which will put x lines per file maximum

```sh
split -l 1 test.txt
```

then use this bash script:

```sh
for f in *; do
   if [$f & 1]
then
  cat "$f" >> res.txt
fi
done
```

this will append one file every two files to res.txt

finally clean the original file with

```
rm test.txt
```

**NB:** Im typing on mobile and havent tested but hopefully you got the idea.
**NB2:** Probably not the most efficient but will get the job done. NB3: I dont add script for deleting the many little files because I dont want to have any liability related to data file loss. Just add a rm command if it match the pattern.